# django multiple user permission decorator

Tags: python, django, python-decorators, user-permissions

I am working on a invoices applicatoin where I have 3 different roles. I've got an administrative employee, financial employee and a client.

All the financial part views are protected by a custom financial employee permission decorator and the same goes for the administrative and client views.

However I want to have the build in django super user to have permission to all the views but somehow this doesn't seem to work. See my example view below:

```
@method_decorator(admin_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(financial_employee_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class InvoiceListView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(complete=False)
```

And these are the decorators:

```
def admin_required(function=None,redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,login_url='home'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
    lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_superuser,
    login_url=login_url,
    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator

def financial_employee_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='home'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
    lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_financial_employee,
    login_url=login_url,
    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name,
)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

This doesn't not work at all. I've only been able to let the superuser login or the financial employee. What am I doing wrong? How am I able to have a view acces by 2 different roles? Because I am trying to prevent to let the superuser work with the django admin panel.

Comment: I think you should write one function accepting superuser OR financial employee

Comment: you may be interested in https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces or https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-role-permissions e.g. if financial employee is the only group you want to use you can mark them as staff

Comment: @PawełKordowski After I posted this question I actually thought of this solution and tried it. It actually works! It works, so stupid of me just think of this solution after posting this question here. But thank you for your help!